# jquery datatable pagination not showing page counts

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi i'm using jquery data table 1.9.4 for population server side processing tables.The data's are loading correctly. but the pagination is not working as expected. Actually it has more than 30 rows and the next,previous and page numbers not working
[image]

```
var sTableAllCustomers = $('#tblAllCustomers').dataTable({
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide" : true,
                "bLenthChange" : false,
                "iDisplayLength": 5,
                "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
                "sAjaxSource" : "loadAllCustomers",
                "oLanguage" : {
                    "sSearch" : "Search By Email ID:"
                },
                "aoColumns" : [
                 {"sTitle" : "No.","mData" : null,"aTargets": [ 0 ],
                    "fnRender" : function(obj) {
                        var columnIndex = obj.oSettings._iDisplayStart + obj.iDataRow+1
                        return columnIndex;
                    }
                },
                {"sTitle" : "Email ID","mData" : "email", "bSearchable" : true},
                {"sTitle" : "Devices","mData" : "device", "bSearchable" : false},
                {"sTitle" : "App Edition","mData" : "edition", "bSearchable" : false},
                {"sTitle" : "Account Type","mData" : "accountType", "bSearchable" : false},
                {"sTitle" : "Activated Date","mData" : "activatedDate", "bSearchable" : false},
                {"mData" : "id", "bSearchable": false,
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full ) {
                         return '<a id="'+data+'" datakey="'+full['key']+'" class="btnViewMoreInAllCustomers btn tooltipped more color-sec" data-tooltip="More" data-position="left"> <i class="mdi-notification-more"></i></a>';
                      }
                }
                ],
                   "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                    $.ajax({
                     "dataType" : 'json',
                     "type" : "GET",
                     "url" : sSource,
                     "data" : aoData,
                     "success" : fnCallback
                    });
                   },
            });
```

The server side code

```
int totalListSize = modals != null ? modals.size() : 0;
        CustomerDataTableObject dataTableObject = new CustomerDataTableObject();
        // the total data in db for datatables to calculate page no. and
        // position
        dataTableObject.setiTotalDisplayRecords(totalListSize);
        // the total data in db for datatables to calculate page no.
        dataTableObject.setiTotalRecords(totalListSize);
        dataTableObject.setsEcho(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sEcho")));
        dataTableObject.setAaData(modals);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(dataTableObject);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing two parameters `iTotalRecords` and `iTotalDisplayRecords` with the same value stored in `totalListSize` variable. However variable `totalListSize` holds the number of records returned, but it should hold total number of records in the database.

From the [documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side):

> `iTotalRecords`
>
> Total records, before filtering (i.e. the total number of records in the database)
>
> `iTotalDisplayRecords`
>
> Total records, after filtering (i.e. the total number of records after filtering has been applied - not just the number of records being returned in this result set)

You need to calculate total number of records in the database separately and assign it to `iTotalRecords` and `iTotalDisplayRecords`.

For example, if you have `30` records and only `5` can be displayed on one page, your response should be something like:

```
{

    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 30,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 30,
    "aaData": [
        {
            "DT_RowId": "row_8",
            "DT_RowClass": "gradeA",
            "0": "Gecko",
            "1": "Firefox 1.5",
            "2": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
            "3": "1.8",
            "4": "A"
        },
        // ... 4 more entries ... 
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your support. i have changed the iTotalRecords with my table's record size. but still not showing only 1 page number on the bottom, actually i have 30 record .

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38213104/revisions

you can refer the above link.

i use the following code in my EntityController

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoadDataAsync([FromForm]JqueryDataTablesParameters parameters)
    {
        var (data, filtered, total) = await GetAllAsync(parameters, "Id", "Code", "Name");

        //Returning Json Data  
        return Json(new JqueryDataTablesResult<GradeDto>
        {
            Draw = parameters.Draw,
            Data = data,
            FilteredRecords = filtered,
            TotalRecords = total
        });
    }
```