# jquery datatables pagination not working

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I am new to jquery datatables, I had a simple function which call ajax and map the response into datatables, that is working but , the pagination is not working properly , any suggestion would be greate. Here is my code.

```
    function loadJson() {

    $('#datatable')
            .dataTable(
                    {
                        "bProcessing" : true,
                        "bPaginate" : true,
                        "bServerSide" : true,
                        "sServerMethod" : "GET",
                        "sAjaxSource" : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/emi/calculate?jsonValue="
                                + jsonData,
                        "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
                        "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData,
                                iDisplayIndex) {
                            $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex + 1);
                            return nRow;
                        },

                        "aoColumns" : [ {
                            "mData" : null
                        }, {
                            "mData" : "emiDate"
                        }, {
                            "mData" : "principle"
                        }, {
                            "mData" : "interestAmount"
                        }, {
                            "mData" : "emi"
                        }, {
                            "mData" : "loanOutstanding"
                        } ]
                    });
}
```

I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NppMK.png) output , the problem is , Show entries is not working and i only have 11 record and i got 1,2,3,4 page number which should only be 1, 2 and only 10 record need to be there . What did i miss here ?

Comment: add this,    "pagingType": "full_numbers","paging": true,

Comment: which error you can got in consol

Comment: no error in console.

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution ,  ya , add but didn't solve.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this,

```
   "pagingType": "full_numbers",
   "paging": true,
   "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
```

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38475379/jquery-datatable-pagination-not-showing-page-counts

Comment: it will help you

Comment: Thanks for you response, well i am new to this ,  working fiddle or any detail working code would be greate.Thanks

Comment: i will see that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this property in your datatable declaration

```
     function loadJson() {

    $('#datatable')
            .DataTable(
                    {

                        "sServerMethod" : "GET",
                        "sAjaxSource" : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/emi/calculate?jsonValue="
                                + jsonData,
                        "sAjaxDataProp" : "",


                        "aoColumns" : [ {
                            "mData" : null
                        }, {
                            "mData" : "emiDate"
                        }, {
                            "mData" : "principle"
                        }, {
                            "mData" : "interestAmount"
                        }, {
                            "mData" : "emi"
                        }, {
                            "mData" : "loanOutstanding"
                        } ],
                        "bProcessing" : true,
                        "bPaginate" : true,
                        "bServerSide" : true
                    });

}
```

Comment: which **js** you can use for data table?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`

Comment: you can use only this js for datatable

Comment: try to use `$('#datatable').DataTable()` like this. **set datatable d to caps**

Comment: $('#datatable').dataTable() , this is what i am using

Comment: i change my code to  `$('#datatable').DataTable()`, but not working

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38213104/revisions

you can refer to the above link.

I use the following code in my `EntityController`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoadDataAsync([FromForm]JqueryDataTablesParameters parameters)
{
    var (data, filtered, total) = await GetAllAsync(parameters, "Id", "Code", "Name");

    //Returning Json Data  
    return Json(new JqueryDataTablesResult<GradeDto>
    {
        Draw = parameters.Draw,
        Data = data,
        FilteredRecords = filtered,
        TotalRecords = total
    });
}
```